# How to skip the value of UnkeyedDecodingContainer while decoding?

Tags: swift

I need to decode a JSON with my custom implementation

```
internal init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container: UnkeyedDecodingContainer = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()

        while !container.isAtEnd {
            if let obj = try? container.decode(Node.self) {
                parserableArr.append(obj)
            }
            else if let obj = try? container.decode(NodeGPU.self) {
                parserableArr.append(obj)
            }
        }
    }
```

So, the flow is - I get `container` and try to decode it with each type one by one. The problem is that if I didn't find the needed type I was stuck in an infinity loop, because the `while !container.isAtEnd` is never stopped.

I am looking for a method like `container.skipValue()`, so I can use it like this

```
...
else {
  container.skipValue()
}
...
```

But there is no such method.

**P.S.** Of course I can use a kind of workaround and provide kind of the dummy implementation in the last `else` state which won't throw, but I am wondering if there is a way to make it work without such a workaround?

Comment: There was a discussion and I think a nice workaround: https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-unkeyeddecodingcontainer-movenext-to-skip-items-in-deserialization/22151/17 but it's still a workaround (it's more or less what you already suggested, just making it in a "method" for the container)., and the MR on the Github hasn't moved since. I wonder if there is still discussion elsewhere...

Comment: https://bugs.swift.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SR-5953

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46344963/swift-jsondecode-decoding-arrays-fails-if-single-element-decoding-fails ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually, I went with this solution - https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-unkeyeddecodingcontainer-movenext-to-skip-items-in-deserialization/22151/17 (thanks to @Larme)

```
struct Empty: Decodable { }

extension UnkeyedDecodingContainer {
  public mutating func skip() throws {
    _ = try decode(Empty.self)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This question was already discussed here:
[Swift JSONDecode decoding arrays fails if single element decoding fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46344963/swift-jsondecode-decoding-arrays-fails-if-single-element-decoding-fails)

You can catch an error and decode a "DummyCodable" like that

```
catch let error {
    _ = try? itemContainer.decode(DummyCodable.self)
}
```

DummyCodable looks like:

```
public struct DummyCodable: Codable {}
```